# Unable to Bind Json to TreeTable Js using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the TreeTable plugin:
http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples

```
<table id="example-basic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th> <th>Status</th> <th>id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: TreeView">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-tt-id': id ,'data-tt-parent-id': Parentid}">
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
 <button type="button" name="test" onclick="test()"></button>
```

The below works if I HardCode as is and the result is shown as a nicely formatted TreeView.

```
ko.applyBindings({ TreeView: [{ "id": "1", "Parentid": null, "Name": "test1", "Status": "OK" }, { "id": "2", "Parentid": 1, "Name": "test2", "Status": "OK" }] }
```

But, I am getting the value from the server(put the value obtained from server in "str" variable) and doing the binding as below:

```
str = '[{ "id": "1", "Parentid": null, "Name": "parent1", "Status": "OK" }, { "id": "2", "Parentid": 1, "Name": "child1", "Status": "OK" }]',
json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")")),
ko.applyBindings({ TreeView: json})

 function reload() {
            //ko.applyBindings({ TreeView: {} });
 str = '[{ "id": "1", "Parentid": null, "Name": "parent1", "Status": "OK" }]'
 json = JSON.parse(str),
ko.applyBindings({ TreeView: json})
```

I get the following error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
 Message: ReferenceError: 'id' is undefined;
Bindings value: `attr: { 'data-tt-id': id ,'data-tt-parent-id': Parentid}`

Can someone please help. Thanks!
The Json object returned had to be converted to type string and then parsed. This resolved the above issue

New Issue:
I was just playing around with the treetable plugin. I wish to reload the data from server on button click(or ajax call every 5 sec). The data is duplicated.

Comment: were you able to figure out the data duplication issue?

Comment: No. The issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stringifying the JSON instead of parsing it, and using `eval()` when you don't need it. Instead, just use `JSON.parse()`.

```
var str = '[{ "id": "1", "Parentid": null, "Name": "parent1", "Status": "OK" }, { "id": "2", "Parentid": 1, "Name": "child1", "Status": "OK" }]';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
ko.applyBindings({ TreeView: json });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There was issue in the way, I was getting the Json object.